# android supporting resolution with multiple layout folder

Tags: android

I am new in android, and want to design the layout which run in all screens resolution of the android devise  ? Is their any way to do this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: when we drop image with same name in all drawable folder. which are conflict in xlarge layout.what can i do.thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes there are way but you will have to take care of few thing..

1. dont fix the size of Layout always use **fill-parent** for layout and for view always use  **wrap_content**

2:  in drawable folder use proper image because proper image called from the drawable folder according to file sie

3.if you face some layout still on not there place then crate layout folder like **values-sw600dp** **values-sw720dp-land** according to you need.

Comment: will you please provide some code about this. its really helpful to me.thanks

Comment: there is no code as such to make your layout proper...you as a coder you only will have to take care.